# How to remove Offers4U Ads from Chrome on Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, adblock, advertisements

My browser will fill up with offers4u ads whenever I open any shopping website.

I have AdBlocker Plus, I've uninstalled all extensions, but still the ads are coming.

Can anyone solve my problem? This is really making me to not to do online shopping. Please help.

Comment: This is not Offers4U advertisement issue, this is adware issue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've managed to remove the adware from my mac. I've used Malwarebytes Anti-Malware for removing. Now all websites are responding properly.

If you want you can install to remove most of the malware or adware and then uninstall it.